# [PHP][MySQL] How to implement a title field for each selected file in an upload form?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm a php/mysql newbie and need your help!
I have an upload formula to upload multiple files to a database, selected one by one.
The files upload works fine, but I want to add a title field for each selected file. I have no idea how to implement this in my code.
 
Here is my code:

```
$db = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "xy");
if (isset($_POST['upload_docs'])) {

   for($mi = 0; $mi < count($_FILES['sel_doc']['tmp_name']); $mi++) {

     $doc = $_FILES['sel_doc']['name'][$mi];
     $tmp_doc = $_FILES['sel_doc']['tmp_name'][$mi];
     $target = "doc_uploads/". basename($doc);

     if (move_uploaded_file($tmp_doc, $target)) {
       echo "Upload successfully!";
     }
     else {
       echo "Upload failed!";
     }
     $sql_f = "INSERT INTO docs (doc_file) VALUES ('$doc')";
     mysqli_query($db, $sql_f);
   }
}



<form method="POST" action="upload.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <div>
      <input type="file" name="sel_doc[]">
      <input type="file" name="sel_doc[]">
      <input type="file" name="sel_doc[]">
      <input type="file" name="sel_doc[]">
      <input type="file" name="sel_doc[]">
   </div>

   <div id="upload_button">
    <button type="submit" name="upload_docs">upload</button>
   </div>
</form>
```

This is how 1 upload would looks like:

```
|    id_doc  |  doc_file |  doc_title|upload_id|
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
|.....1......|...a.pdf...|....vvv....|....1....|
|.....2......|...b.pdf...|....www....|....1....|
|.....3......|...c.pdf...|....xxx....|....1....|
|.....4......|...d.pdf...|....yyy....|....1....|
|.....5......|...e.pdf...|....zzz....|....1....|
```

In my orginal code I insert in 2 tables for 1:n realationship (because of the "upload_id").

Comment: You probably want corresponding text input fields, e.g. `<input type="text" name="sel_title[]" ... />` then marry them up to the files by their indexes. To be on the safe side you could specify those indexes, e.g. `<input type="file" name="sel_doc[1]" /> ... <input type="text" name="sel_title[1]" ... />`

Comment: and how would you bring it through the for loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTML

```
<div>
<?php for ($i=0; $i<5; $i++){ ?>
    <b><?php echo $i ?></b><br>
    File: <input type="file" name="sel_doc[<?php echo $i ?>]"><br>
    Title: <input name="title[<?php echo $i ?>]"><br>
<?php } ?>
</div>
```

Will print this:

```
<div>
    <b>0</b><br>
    File: <input type="file" name="sel_doc[0]"><br>
    Title: <input name="title[0]"><br>
    <b>1</b><br>
    File: <input type="file" name="sel_doc[1]"><br>
    Title: <input name="title[1]"><br>
    <b>2</b><br>
    File: <input type="file" name="sel_doc[2]"><br>
    Title: <input name="title[2]"><br>
    <b>3</b><br>
    File: <input type="file" name="sel_doc[3]"><br>
    Title: <input name="title[3]"><br>
    <b>4</b><br>
    File: <input type="file" name="sel_doc[4]"><br>
    Title: <input name="title[4]"><br>
</div>
```

PHP code

```
$db = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "xy");
if (isset($_POST['upload_docs'])) {

   for($mi = 0; $mi < count($_FILES['sel_doc']['tmp_name']); $mi++) {

     $doc = $_FILES['sel_doc']['name'][$mi];
     $tmp_doc = $_FILES['sel_doc']['tmp_name'][$mi];
     $target = "doc_uploads/". basename($doc);
     $title = (isset($_POST['title'][$mi])?$_POST['title'][$mi]:"");

     if (move_uploaded_file($tmp_doc, $target)) {
       echo "Upload successfully!";
     }
     else {
       echo "Upload failed!";
     }
     $sql_f = "INSERT INTO docs (doc_file, title) VALUES ('$doc', '$title')";
     mysqli_query($db, $sql_f);
   }
}
```

Btw; This example code is not safe for **sql injection**.

Comment: Thank you very much! This works great! The security stuff I want do at the end, when i'm more experienced. It is just editing and adding code, right? Or do i have to build a security structure from the beginning?

Comment: @user10235329 ... **never** treat security as an afterthought ;) Just read up on mysqli/PDO, Prepared Statements with Bound Parameters and you won't go far wrong (with regards to SQL injection anyway).

Comment: But everything would be possible to add later? :) I'm a php&mysqli newbie and I'm focused to building my first website project. But yes, i should through an eye on the prepared statements...

Comment: A other question about the upload form, what do i have to change, that for the first file, there is only 1 select button + title field and when 1 file is selected and there is written something in the title field, then there will be added a new button and title field and so on and so forth ... do you have a quick solution or should i do a new "Ask Question" for this?

Comment: You have to do that with Javascript. I would suggest to ask a new question for that

Comment: in php it isn't possible with any loop function?

Comment: PHP runs serverside. So than you have to post the FORM to the server. Javascript runs clientside so the client (browser) can change the HTML "live"